# Как выключить обновление Windows?

Tags: windows, update, windows-10

Использую 3G модем, поэтому экономлю каждый мегабайт трафика. Чтобы разные программы "не лазили" в Интернет, открыл в брандмауэре только 80 и 443 порты.

Но Windows скачал обновления. Хорошо, что хотя бы вовремя увидел. В *Windows 10 Preview* я не нашёл пункт *"устанавливать обновления автоматически"*, поэтому поискал в Интернете и уставил ключ в реестр:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update] 
"AUOptions"=dword:00000001
```

Есть ли теперь гарантия, что Windows больше не будет скачивать обновления? Или что мне нужно для этого сделать?

Куда идут запросы обновления? Может, запретить в брандмауэре этот адрес? Или запросы идут поверх брандмауэра?

Comment: Было бы здорово, если бы вы перестали добавлять отступы в каждой строке каждого своего вопроса/ответа. Отступы (`\t` или 4 пробела) нужны для выделения кода, а не для всего текста. Раз за разом ведь приводят ваш текст в нормальный вид, а вы всё равно продолжаете неправильно оформлять посты.

Comment: Все попытки полезть в сеть не удастся побороть таким образом - если не винда, так что-то другое. Поэтому самый очевидный вариант - это файрволл на уровне самого модема(исходя из возможности того, что внутренние механизмы винды могут обходить коробочный брандмауэр в крайних случаях). Другой вопрос, предоставляет ли производитель модема такой файрвол. Обычно это выясняется, пошерстив веб-интерфейс управления.

Answer (score 5):

Правильный, поддерживаемый Microsoft способ — групповые политики.

Откройте редактор локальных групповых политик (<kbd>Win + R</kbd> — `gpedit.msc`), зайдите в *Computer Configuration* → *Administrative Templates* → *Windows Components* → *Windows Update*. Выберите *Configure Automatic Updates* и настройте как вам нужно.

---

Редактирование реестра — грубый хак, Microsoft не давала гарантий, что имена нужных ключей реестра не поменяются в зависимости от фазы луны и направления ветра. Не пользуйтесь им.

---

Групповые политики доступны для версий Windows старше Home. Но если вы хотите настроить систему под себя, вы ведь не будете сидеть на версии для *начинающих*?

Comment: Ну зачем так про хомячка-то, настраивается он нормально, даже без хаков с реестром, правда маленько через известное место =). Но в остальном полностью солидарен.

Comment: @rdorn: Если есть хороший путь и для Home Edition, может быть, напишете отдельным ответом?

Comment: ответил, только на дату вопроса не посмотрел =) ну да ладно, пусть будет, может кому понадобится

Answer (score 2):

Если мешают именно обновления, то для большинства версий семейства WinNT (скорее всего для всех, но не могу проверить совсем древние) самый простой и надежный  вариант отключить службу обновлений совсем.

Для этого (требуются права локального администратора):

- заходим в список служб любым привычным способом, например <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> => вкладка "Службы" => кнопка "Службы..." или <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> => services.msc
- Находим в списке "Центр обновления Windows"
- Двойной клик по службе и в открывшемся диалоге:

  - меняем тип запуска на "Отключена"
  - жмем кнопку "Остановить"
  - жмем "Ок".

На этом все, обновления проверяться перестанут, совсем, даже ручной режим будет не доступен. Если они вдруг понадобятся, то проделать все тоже самое, но при этом вернуть автоматический запуск службы и принудительно ее запустить, ну или дождаться перезагрузки.

Аналогичным образом можно поступить и с другими службами, но будьте осторожны, не все службы можно так безболезненно выключить. Некоторые не даст выключить сама система, а некоторые могут быть необходимы для работы ваших программ, так что предварительно стоит изучить данный вопрос, а потом уже рубить все что рубится.

Для  Pro версий, также можно через групповые политики прописать localhost в качестве источника обновлений. В этом случае постороннего трафика возникать не будет, т.к все запросы будут заворачиваться обратно без использования внешнего соединения, но потребуется разобраться в редакторе групповой политики. Этот путь несколько сложнее и для одной-двух машин не слишком актуален, хотя если у вас их десяток другой, то стоит изучить групповые политики и их возможности максимально подробно, чтобы не заниматься любительским вело-строением. Возможности эти гораздо шире, чем о них пишут на современных популярных ресурсах.

---

Что касается всех остальных программ - вопрос решается грамотной настройкой встроенного или стороннего брандмауэра. Под грамотной настройкой в данном случае следует понимать режим "Белого списка" (что не разрешено явно, то запрещено) для **программ**, а не протоколов или портов, т.к. открытые порты и протоколы вполне могут использовать и другие программы, в отличие от явного указания разрешенных программ.

---

**PS:** не трогайте реестр руками, особенно если не уверены в том, что делаете (только что нагуглили, спросили у знакомого "хакера" и т.д.). Угробить его довольно легко, а вот восстановление, даже на Win7, самой не убиваемой из семейства, может оказаться серьезной проблемой.

Answer (score -3):

Есть гарантия, но не стопудовая, как ехинацею можна использовать файл hosts, с помощью снифера узнать на какие сервера "лезит" обновлялка Виндовс, и скопировать эти URL в файл hosts.

Детальней про файл hosts: https://www.chaynikam.net/view_lesson.php?id=80